# My code seems to execute in a wrong order

Tags: c++

i wrote a print function as follows.

```
#define NDEBUG
void print(vector<int> &vec)
{
#ifdef NDEBUG
    std::cout << "vector size: " << vec.size() << std::endl;
#endif
    if (!vec.empty())
    {
        auto temp = vec.back();
        vec.pop_back();
        print(vec);
        std::cout << temp<<std::endl;

    }
}
```

it prints:

```
vector sise:6
vector sise:5
vector sise:4
vector sise:3
vector sise:2
vector sise:1
vector sise:0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

but I expect it to be something like:

```
vector sise:6
6
vector sise:5
5
vector sise:4
4
vector sise:3
3
vector sise:2
2
vector sise:1
1
vector sise:0
```

Is is Because of Priority of threads? if it is, how can I control the right execution order as my code?

Comment: You speak of thread but you code show nothing related to thread. Please update your question with a sscce.

Comment: Your output doesn't match your code. The "sise" as mentioned, and the space after the colon.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**

The following lines are inverted:

```
    print(vec);
    std::cout << temp<<std::endl;
```

They should be:

```
    std::cout << temp<<std::endl;
    print(vec);
```

**Rationale**

If you look at your code when the input vector has got size 6, you will first output the size:

```
std::cout << "vector size: " << vec.size() << std::endl;
```

Then you will call your function recursively:

```
    print(vec);
```

And only after this recursive call return you print the 6th item:

```
    std::cout << temp<<std::endl;
```

Then you return from your function. So it's clear that the 6th item will print last. The same reasoning apply to the recursive calls and explain your output.

Comment: if it is recursive why does 'cout' work after function call?

Comment: Because you write to `cout` **after** calling your function recursively. I updated my rationale.

Comment: thank you. i have one more question. the thing that made me confused is that, if i 'cout' before function call the output will be logical but when inverted  it seems to pop the front of the vector and print 1 2 3 4 5 6 . why does it happen? the argument of the function is a 'vector<int>={1,2,3,4,5,6}'

Comment: Because the first output with cout will be when the vector is empty when you call `print(vec)`, this happens when you've just popped the 1st element. Then the function will return and you will print the last item saved by the caller, which will be the 2nd item, and so on.

Comment: if the first output with cout will be when the  vector is empty , so the vector is empty and its condition is false and if-block must not execute.

Comment: No, the vector is empty because you've just popped from it: `vec.pop_back(); print(vec); std::cout << temp<<std::endl;`. And indeed, the recursive call to `print(vec)` won't do anything. That's why this will be the first time you output to `cout`

Comment: why it continue executing after the the vector is empty and the condition is false? how it print the element from an empty vector?

Comment: The condition was true, you emptied the vector inside the condition.

Comment: I am not persuaded because vec is not local for if-block and it is a reference to the vector defined in the main. so the recursive function call inside the if-block passes the same popped vector each time so vec will be empty certainly after six call. i know there is a trick in between but what is that exactly? does not poping a vector delete its element?

Comment: you said it emptied vector inside the condition. and did not understand what you mean.

Comment: When the vector has got size 1, you enter the condition, get the last element, which is the 1st of the initial vector, pop back, and pass the empty vector to `print(vec)`, which does nithing because the vector is now empty. Then you print to `cout`.

Comment: oh i got it. but if so , each time it must print the first element from initial vector. so how does is iterate the vector's element?

Comment: No, each time it prints the last element of the current vector. When the size is 1, the last element is the 1st of the original vector. When size is 2, it is the 2nd element of the original vector and so on.

Comment: excuse me for asking too many questions . this question have been always bothering me.

Answer (score 3):

You call `print` recursively before you output `temp`. Think of it like this (with a smaller example):

```
print vec(2)
    cout size: 2
    print vec(1)
    cout size: 1
        print vec(0)
        cout size: 0
    cout 1
cout 2
```

You need to output before recursing:

```
std::cout << temp << std::endl;
print(vec);
```